# how to pass variable from html to js directly from onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I want to send variables from html to javascript file onclick some button. Can I write something like:

```
onclick="xFunc(document.getElementsByName("x").value,document.getElementsByName("y").value,document.getElementsByName("z").value);"></p>
```

because the javascript inside html does not works! I try: 
`<script>` tag and `<script type="text/javascript">` tag and `<script language ="javascript">` tag and nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try any of the below:

If you want to get value from tag name.

`onclick="xFunc(document.getElementsByName('x')[0].value,document.getElementsByName('y')[0].value,document.getElementsByName('z')[0].value)"`

If you want to get value from tag id. i prefer this.

`onclick="xFunc(document.getElementById('x').value,document.getElementById('y').value,document.getElementById('z').value)"`

Note: Id is different from name

Answer (score 1):

You must use single quote character instead of quote character.Also `getElementsByName` returns an array. Either you can choose one element from array depending of what you want to do or you can use `getELementById`.

```
// passing just one element of array
    <p onclick="xFunc(document.getElementsByName('x')[0].value,document.getElementsByName('y')[0].value,document.getElementsByName('z')[0].value);"></p>

// passing the whole array 
    <p onclick="xFunc(document.getElementsByName('x')[0],document.getElementsByName('y')[0],document.getElementsByName('z')[0]);"></p>


// Using getElementById
// in this case you must use Id attribute for your elements
//  <mytag  id="x"></mytag>
<p onclick="xFunc(document.getElementById('x'),document.getElementById('y'),document.getElementById('z'));"></p>
```